# unable to get the index property of the worksheetfunction class error 104

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to return a random selection into a textbox on a form with a button click from a range I have built in a worksheet and keep getting this error.  Here is the code I have written.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

TextBox1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index("Codes!A3:K66", Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(3, 64), Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 11))

End Sub
```

Comment: `"Codes!A3:K66"` needs to be `Worksheets("Codes").Range("A3:K66")`

Comment: @ScottCraner is right, you can't write the range in VBA as a string

Answer (score 0):

`"Codes!A3:K66"` needs to be `Worksheets("Codes").Range("A3:K66")`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

TextBox1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index("Codes!A3:K66", Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(3, 64), Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 11))

End Sub
```

But you can also do:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    TextBox1.Value = Worksheets("Codes").Cells(.RandBetween(3, 66), .RandBetween(1, 11)).Value
End With
End Sub
```

And skip the INDEX